# Change Color of List Item on Focus

Tags: android, listview

I am facing problem with  **list-view**, When  **List-view** is focused i want to change the text-color of Text-view in  **list-item** alone and i Want to display an image in list-item at right corner.

Following code i have used.

In Xml of main class

```
              <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listViewMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@null"
                    android:divider="@color/titlebar_divider"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
                </ListView>
```

In Adapter xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMenuImages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/my_page" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMenuNames"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/mypage"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_textcolor"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFocusImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Adapter JavaCode.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_row, null);

        TextView mTextView = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMenuNames);
        mImageView = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgMenuImages);
        imgFocusImage = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgFocusImage);
        imgFocusImage.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        mImageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        mTextView.setText(mIndicators[position]);

        mTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                v.setBackgroundColor(hasFocus ? Color.GRAY : Color.BLACK);
            }
        });

        imgFocusImage.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if(hasFocus)
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }
```

While Focusing, I can change the color of `Listitem` in `ListView`,But when it is pressed it working.

In Selector.xml

```
<item android:color="#FCBC04" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#FCBC04" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- focused and pressed -->
<item android:color="#FCBC04" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:color="#D8D8D8"/>
<!-- default -->
```

Thank You!!

Comment: you just want to  change the color of your textfield alone but not the whole List view ?

Comment: try to change inflate layout background as @drawable/Selector. i think it will work

Comment: about which layout r u speaking..

Comment: @UsmanKurd, yes i want to change color textview only but not listview

Answer (score 0):

in Res folder 
add color folder and in color 
add a selector 
use ca use it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:color="@color/bluetxt"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/whiteColor"></item> 
</selector>
```

here blutxt and whitecolor are my own custom color u can use it your own as your requirment